# flask render_template with url parameter

Tags: templates, flask, pdf.js

I use pdf.js to render pdf in web. The format of the target url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/book?file=abc.pdf
```

My problem is:
I use flask template to generate page using:

```
return render_template('book.html', paraKey=paraValue)
```

But how to attach url parameter "file=abc.pdf" to url?
The parameter will be read by viewer.js(included in book.html) that uses it to read file for rendering pdf.

I'm new to flask, hoping guys giving me some help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use redirect function, which can redirect you whatever you want:

```
@app.route('/book')
def hello():
    file = request.args.get('file')
    if not file:
        return redirect("/?file=abc.pdf")
    return render_template('book.html', paraKey=paraValue)
```

Comment: Much obliged, Bryzzhin! It works! steps is:1)attach parameter to url;2)using render_template generate target page which contains parameter.Now I will not change any js files.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parameter that have been passed in the request url by using the request object.

```
    @app.route("/book", methods=["GET"])
    def get_book():
        file = request.args.get("file")
        if file:
            return render_template('book.html', file=file)
        abort(401, description="Missing file parameter in request url")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but render_template cannot let parameter("file" in here) be read by js file.I find a method to resolve it written in the following answer, but it seems not the best choice!

Comment: so why they remove the paramters when return render_template in post and why wtform need render_template then

Answer (score 1):

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template) helped me reslove my question, but it seems not the perfect answer.
code **viewer.py** not changed.Solution is:

step1)I embed the code

```
<script>var FILE_PATH = {{ file }}</script>
```

in template.

step2)the script that will use the variable need to modify the code(**viewer.js**),from:

```
var file = 'file' in params ? params.file : DEFAULT_URL
```

to

```
var file = FILE_PATH ? FILE_PATH: DEFAULT_URL
```

It let **viewer.js** not independent anymore.

I hope someone provide a better solution.