# JSON Parse not working appropriately with JSON-formatted string

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, google-maps

I'm having an issue using JSON.parse. app.py sends 3 arrays of JSON objects to index.html: state_latitude, state_longitude, and state_name.

app.py

```
def index():
    """Render map"""
    if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):
        raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")
    state_latitude = db.execute("SELECT latitude FROM geo_states")
    state_longitude = db.execute("SELECT longitude FROM geo_states")
    state_name = db.execute("SELECT name FROM geo_states")
    return render_template("index.html", key=os.environ.get("API_KEY"), state_latitude=json.dumps(state_latitude), state_longitude=json.dumps(state_longitude), 
         state_name=json.dumps(state_name))
```

index.html

The short script in index.html is meant to define variables that can be accessed by scripts.js. They are still the same 3 arrays return by the python script, but now they are formatted as strings. When I tried to define state_lats, state_longs, and state_names as `var state_lats = {{ state_latitude }}` for example, I receive an error "Parsing error: Unexpected token {". If I can define these three variables as JSONs rather than strings, that would be one way of solving this issue, but because I wasn't able to figure that out. I tried to work with them as strings in scripts.js.

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var state_latitudes = "{{ state_latitude }}"
    var state_longitudes = "{{ state_longitude }}"
    var state_names = "{{ state_name }}"
</script>
<script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>
```

scripts.js

state_latitudelist (and the other two equivalent variables) is an array of strings that are in JSON format, rather than being one long string containing multiple JSONs. The value for state_latitudelist is below. I tried to iterate over this array and convert each element to an actual JSON, so that I can index into them later in the script, but it does not appear to be working. I'm not receiving an error, but when I attempt to do `document.write(statelatitudeJSON)` the command appears to be ignored, which suggests that statelatitudeJSON is empty. Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
var state_latitudelist = [];
var value = "";
var addValue = false;
for (i = 0; i < state_latitudes.length; i++) {
    if (state_latitudes[i] == '{') {
        addValue = true;
    }
    if (state_latitudes[i] == '}') {
        addValue = false;
        value += state_latitudes[i];
        state_latitudelist.push(value);
        value = '';
    }
    if (addValue == true) {
        value += state_latitudes[i];
    }
}
var state_latitudeJSON = []
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     state_latitudeJSON.push(JSON.parse(state_latitudelist[i]))
}
```

`document.write(state_latitudelist)` returns

```
{"latitude": 32.806671},{"latitude": 61.370716},{"latitude": 33.729759},{"latitude": 34.969704},{"latitude": 36.116203},{"latitude": 39.059811},{"latitude": 41.597782},{"latitude": 39.318523},{"latitude": 38.897438},{"latitude": 27.766279},{"latitude": 33.040619},{"latitude": 21.094318},{"latitude": 44.240459},{"latitude": 40.349457},{"latitude": 39.849426},{"latitude": 42.011539},{"latitude": 38.5266},{"latitude": 37.66814},{"latitude": 31.169546},{"latitude": 44.693947},{"latitude": 39.063946},{"latitude": 42.230171},{"latitude": 43.326618},{"latitude": 45.694454},{"latitude": 32.741646},{"latitude": 38.456085},{"latitude": 46.921925},{"latitude": 41.12537},{"latitude": 38.313515},{"latitude": 43.452492},{"latitude": 40.298904},{"latitude": 34.840515},{"latitude": 42.165726},{"latitude": 35.630066},{"latitude": 47.528912},{"latitude": 40.388783},{"latitude": 35.565342},{"latitude": 44.572021},{"latitude": 40.590752},{"latitude": 41.680893},{"latitude": 33.856892},{"latitude": 44.299782},{"latitude": 35.747845},{"latitude": 31.054487},{"latitude": 40.150032},{"latitude": 44.045876},{"latitude": 37.769337},{"latitude": 47.400902},{"latitude": 38.491226},{"latitude": 44.268543},{"latitude": 42.755966}
```

Comment: Is that flask? If so, check [this question and its answers out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template). I don't think you need to do `json.dumps` I think it would just be `state_name=state_name`. The template would use `var state_names = {{ state_name|tojson }}`