# Using data saved as a variable in HTML from Python

Tags: python, html, flask, chart.js, jinja2

**Is it possible to have a variable that is defined in a python file be passed through to a html file in the same directory and used in a 'script' tag?**

Synopsis: 
Im producing a flask website that pulls data from a database and uses it to create a line chart in chartjs. Flask uses jijna to manage templates. The data in the databse has been normalised so that it can be read by the chart script (label is in a list, data as a tuple). So far I have produced routes so that each page can be accessed and passed the value into the return_template parameter as shown here:

```
@app.route('/room2')
def room2():
    return render_template('room2.html', title = 'Room2', time = newLabel, count = newData )
```

with the html for the room being called along with the title which is accessed here:

```
{% if title %}
    <title>Website title - {{ title }}</title>
{% else%}
    <title>Website</title>
{% endif %}
```

The chart is being generated in the html file, and I want to take the data (time and count) and use it in the script the same way the title is used. However the script for chart.js doesnt take {{ }} (which is essentially a print function anyway). So far ive managed to get the data i want INTO the required html file, which is proven by the data being printed out onto the page itself but im not sure how to translate it into a variable to be used by chartjs.

Any suggestions?
(NOTE: using routes like this may be the wrong starting point but it's one that makes logical sense and hasn't produced any errors beside logical)

Files:

- data.py: Takes information from database and converts it into two variables;

```
label = ['09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00']
data = ['4,7,2,3,9,9,5]
```

- routes.py: holds the routes to all the pages,
- layout.html: holds overarching html code for website,
- room.html: holds graph, extends from layout

Comment: You can't use Jinja expressions in a static loaded `script.js` file.  You either need to put a `<script>` block in the *template* with some JS like `var myVar = {{variable}};` or another good method would be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840756/2052575) which uses a data attribute of an HTML tag, and retrieves this in Javascript code.  However for loading more complicated objects (x,y cords, etc) it may be advisable to use the fetch API to make a separate request on page load.  I'll see if I can write an answer demonstrates the latter method.

Comment: @v25 im using the jinja expression in a html file and the data is being sent there via an `@app.route('/room2')` in a py file, but i will try to make the variable as suggested (ill use let instead of var although the two are proobably interchangeable right?) Thank you for writing the demonstration i think that will help me understand what you mean

Comment: @v25 so i used the `let myVar = '{{variable}}';` (was getting an error if the single quotes werent there) within the script, which printed out the graph but in an interesting way: the lines of the line chart werent connected to each other, and the labels in the y axis werent correct (will add an image to the post to show update)

Comment: I've added an in-depth answer with a sensible approach.  If you have trouble porting your data into this format in python, please edit your question with a data sample (rather than screenshots) and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I was finishing off other requirements for the project. The way youve explained everything has been really helpful, thank you, so while I look at your repo and see if i can apply what you told me I will put in a data set, the different roots and the current files and what they contain.

Comment: @v25 took a while but i managed it, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beginners who try to put Flask and ChartJS together, a common approach seems to be to write Jinja code which uses loops to output Javascript, or manually uses Jinja expressions within the JS.  This can quick become a maintenence nightmare.

Here's my approach which lets you define the data you want charted in Python, place a canvas in your template with some minimal JS, then dynamically update the chart using the Javascript Fetch API.

You can clone the repo [flask-chartjs](https://github.com/vulcan25/flask-chartjs/tree/0.0.1).

You can have one route which renders the page containing the chart:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', CHART_ENDPOINT = url_for('data'))
```

`CHART_ENDPOINT` in this case will be `/data` which corresponds to another route which returns the JSON.  I also have a helper function which converts epoch times to a ISO 8601 compatible format, which works with moment.

```
import datetime as DT
def conv(epoch):
    return DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch).isoformat()

@app.route('/data')
def data():
    d = {'datasets':
            [
                {'title': 'From Dict',
                 'data': [ {'x': conv(1588745371), 'y': 400},
                           {'x': conv(1588845371), 'y': 500},
                           {'x': conv(1588946171), 'y': 800} ]
                },
            ]
         }

    return jsonify(d)
```

Now in the template you can place the chart's canvas element with `data-endpoint` attribute:

```
<canvas id="canvas" data-endpoint='{{CHART_ENDPOINT}}'></canvas>
```

Then I've implemented two JS functions which in that same template allow you to create the chart, and load the data from the provided endpoint:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');

    myChart = create_chart(ctx);

    window.onload = function () { 
      load_data(myChart)
    };
</script>
```

In the [`create_chart` function](https://github.com/vulcan25/flask-chartjs/blob/fe54a7278808ceca635b5ad5ab8801ea09799c32/static/flask_chart.js#L47-L58) the endpoint is obtained from the `data-endpoint` attrib, and added to the `config` object before it is assigned to that chart [(credit)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840756/2052575):

> ```
> config.endpoint = ctx.dataset.endpoint;
> return new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), config);
> ```

The `load_data` function then accesses the endpoint from `chart.config.endpoint` meaning it always grabs the correct data for the provided chart.

---

You can also set the [time units](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units) when creating the chart:

```
myChart = create_chart(ctx, 'hour') # defaults to 'day'
```

I've found this usually needs to be tweaked depending on your data range.

It would be trivial to modify that code to obtain this in the same manner as the endpoint, within the `create_chart` function.  Something like `config.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = ctx.datasets.unit` if the attribute was `data-unit`.  This could also be done for other variables.

---

You can also pass a string from the frontend when loading data (say `dynamicChart` is another chart, created with the method above):

```
load_data(dynamicChart, 'query_string')
```

This would make `'query_string'` available in the flask function as `request.args.get('q')`

This is useful if you want to implement (for example) a text input field which sends the string to the backend, so the backend can process it somehow and return a customised dataset which is rendered on the chart.  The `/dynamic` route in the repo kind of demonstrates this.

Here's what it looks like rendered:

[image: rendered chart]

As you can see it's possible then to have multiple charts on one page also.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same jinja templating feature to access your Variable in js too.

Maybe if you want strings you should enclose them like this `"{{variable}}"`

Comment: @Code_Yard I tried putting the variable in the {{ }} brackets and put it in the required place in the script but I was getting an error (ill update the question to show you)