# Python Flask list formatting not working inside script tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass a list from my python flask app to the inside of a script tag in my HTML. The data is successfully moving into the javascript, however, it is not being interpreted as the list that I originally created. Instead, the entire list is being converted into a character array which is effectively splitting all of my values into their component parts. How can I preserve the integrity of my lists?

```
{% block page_content %}
{{dates}}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: '{{dates|tojson|safe}}',
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Stonk Price',
                data:  '{{prices|tojson|safe}}',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
{% endblock %}
```

My flask app looks like

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    dates, prices = dayMonthCloseLists("AAPL") # returns 'mm-dd-yyyy' string and float objects as two lists
    return render_template('index.html', dates=dates, prices=prices)
```

Example of the original list being sliced into chars on the x-axis:

[image: 1]

I'm very new to this so I'm unsure if there is just a simple syntax solution.

Comment: Hey, hope my answer can help you, if a slightly different approach.  Let me know if anything's not clear :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61684415/2052575) before on how to use chartjs with flask.  The aim was to avoid building JS code with Jinja2 expressions.  I've created [a branch on that repo](https://github.com/vulcan25/flask-chartjs/tree/65187462) for your usecase.

I created two endpoints, one which returns the JSON data, and another which renders the index page with the chart.  The JSON data is [obtained by the fetch API, then pushed to the chart config object](https://github.com/vulcan25/flask-chartjs/blob/46d05dce085a6cccc0d14624f74ebe2b34ae679a/static/flask_chart.js#L73-L90).  This avoids the need to mix Jinja2 syntax with javascript.

The `app.py` includes:

A `conv` function which changes your date format to an isoformat supported by moment JS:

```
def conv(date_str):
    return DT.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y').isoformat()
```

Then a `data` function, which builds a dict compatible with the frontend:

I've mocked `dates` and `prices`, but you'd just load these with your `dayMonthCloseLists` function:

```
@app.route('/data')
def data():
    ''' Endpoint which returns jsonified data '''

    dates = ['01-02-2020', '02-02-2020', '03-03-2020']
    prices = [1.4, 2.5, 9.6]

    sample_list =[dict(x=conv(date), y=prices[idx]) for idx,date in enumerate(dates)]

    d = {'datasets':
            [
                {'title': 'From Dict',
                 'data': sample_list,
                },
            ],
        }

    return jsonify(d)
```

`sample_list` in the above code looks like this:

```
[{'x': '2020-01-02T00:00:00', 'y': 1.4},
 {'x': '2020-02-02T00:00:00', 'y': 2.5},
 {'x': '2020-03-03T00:00:00', 'y': 9.6}]
```

I then pass the url for the above route to a template as `CHART_ENDPOINT`:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    ''' Route which renders the chart page.  Pass the endpoint which returns jsonified data '''
    return render_template('index.html', CHART_ENDPOINT = url_for('data'))
```

Which can then be included in the `index.html` template like:

```
<canvas id="canvas" data-endpoint='{{CHART_ENDPOINT}}'></canvas>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
    myChart = create_chart(ctx, unit='month');
    window.onload = function() {
      load_data(myChart)
    };
</script>
```

Note the `<head>` section in this template also includes the `moment.min.js` library from cdnjs, which is required for the date conversions, aswell as the `chart.min.js` include too.

You can view the file `flask_chart.js` which handles all of this in the attached repo.  The end result is a chart like:

[image: happy chart]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply! I am able to understand the majority of your comment, however, after applying your code suggestions I cannot render the chart to my webpage. Do you have any clue why this may be?

Comment: @CarmenFerrone feel free to log an issue against my repo