# How to get dataset from MySQL using Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, raspberry-pi, chart.js

I used Arduino to send sensor data to a Raspberry pi, (such as temperature, humidity, smoke level, etc.) Raspberry pi stored them and committed to MySQL database. I am now displaying the dataset on a web server using Flask.

In my python code, I have access to the database.

```
def getTemps():
  cursor = dbConn.cursor()
  result = cursor.execute(sql)
  if result > 0:
    tempDetails = curcor.fetchall()
  return render_template("temp.html", tempDetails=tempDetails)
```

Now, I am able to display them in a table on html like below

```
{% for data in tempDetails %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ data[0] }}</td>
  <td>{{ data[1] }}</td>
  <td>{{ data[2] }}</td>
  <td>{{ data[3] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

p.s: data[0] is id, data[1] is temperature, data[2] is humidity, data[3] is timestamp.

However, I wanted to put them in a graph too, I tried to use `Chart.js`, but I am not sure how to put my list of temperature (and or humidity) in the dataset.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: [/* I want to display each timestamp*/],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [/* in here should i use the {% for data in tempDetails %} for loop again?*/]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!!! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help pass the data from flask to js: [How can I pass data from Flask to JavaScript in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template)

Quote:
" You can use {{ variable }} anywhere in your template, not just in the HTML part. So this should work:

```
<html>
        <head>
          <script>
            var someJavaScriptVar = '{{ geocode[1] }}';
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <button onclick="alert('Geocode: {{ geocode[0] }} ' + someJavaScriptVar)" />
    </body>
</html>
```

"