# Get ReferenceError when reading data sent by Flask in a js script embedded in a template

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have the following Flask interface.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect
app = Flask( __name__)

@app.route("/")
def index(message=None):
    return render_template('home.html', message=message)

@app.route("/viewer", methods=['POST'])
def viewer():
    chr = request.form['chr']
    print("chr %s"%chr)
    return render_template('viewer.html', chr=chr)
```

home.html

```
 [...]
 <form id="inForm" action="/viewer" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="chr" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="all">all</option>
        <option value="chrM">chrM</option>
        <option value="chr1">chr1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

viewer.html

```
<body>

     {{ chr }}

<script type="module">
    var chr_g = {{ chr }};
    console.log("chr_g " + chr_g)

</script>

</body>
```

In `home.html` I choose `chr = chrM`, then submit and the `viewer.html` is loaded.

`chr` is correctly displayed in the html section, but in the JS console I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: chrM is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5000/viewer:25
```

I've followed the answer given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template), with no luck.
Any idea what I am missing?

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewer.html`, I was not saving the value of `{{ chr }}` as a string of text.

```
[..]
<script type="module">
    var chr_g = "{{ chr }}";
    console.log("chr_g " + chr_g)
</script>
```

now it works.