# ReferenceError: 'message' is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, flask

There is a problem in the line  `const message = JSON.parse(message);`. The message is a JSON which is coming from backend in python flask. If I normally write `<span>{{message}}</span>` in HTML tags, this prints out the JSON file. But I cannot parse it for some reason?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - Status Checker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/styles.css') }}">
      
        

<script>

    const message = JSON.parse(message);
</script>
    
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul>
            <li>
             <span>TestDrive</span>
             <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Operational</span>
            </li>
         </ul>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python method:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Me'}
 
------------------------------------------------DATA--------------------


    message=json.dumps(dicts)
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, message = message)
```

JSON:

```
{"thing":"value",
  "more":"stuff"}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `const message = JSON.parse(message)` inside `window.onload = function() { }`?

Comment: No, I dont have an idea of what that is. <script>
    
window.onload = function() { 
    const message = JSON.parse(message);
}
    

</script> Tried this, didnt work :/

Comment: Add the Python method from where you are sending the json.

Comment: added the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the json object after doing `json.dumps`.

```
message = json.dumps(dicts)
message_dump = json.loads(message)
return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, message=message_dump)
```

Now, you can use the json object directly without parsing in the script tag and parse the key values by iterating through it.

Now, you can use like `{{ message["things"] }}` for printing the `"value"` in HTML and so on.

Comment: It still gives message not defined when trying to even use console.log(message) in script

Comment: You don't need the script tag now, you can directly iterate the `message` key values in jinja template HTML.

Comment: How would I iterate them? something like this? {{message[0]}}? That still gives me only the character of '{' instead of the first key value.

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you check with that?

Comment: You have to pass `message_dump` in `render_template` instead of `message`.

Comment: And can i use this method somehow in javascript? because I have to put some if statements which depends on the value of the key?

Comment: You can also use `if, else` in jinja also depending on the key, but that is not what the question is about. Are you able to iterate through the message json?

Comment: Yes, I am able to iterate through it now, but for the usability purposes, isnt it better to parse it to json in javascript so i can make my functions dynamic?

Comment: I would recommend you to ask a different question about that.

Comment: Thank you, i figured out the rest of the syntax for javascript processing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you need to parse it like that:

```
let message = {{ message }} 
JSON.parse(message)
```

So the problem is that template variables are parsed by the server, but you are trying to pass them into JS (browser)

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data.

Comment: updated the answer ) relying to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template the problem was about quotes

Comment: It gives the same error somehow :/

Comment: ok, lets try to remove the quotes

Answer (score -1):

Define message before using it in JSON.parse.

Comment: This is not an answer, you can comment.

Comment: reference error coming because ‘message’ variable not defined.

Comment: @ParthS007 checkout [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined) for more info.