# Send variable from Flask route to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask, stripe-payments

Need help understanding how to send variables from a Flask route to a JavaScript file and visa versa.

Let's say I have the below Flask route:

```
@payment.route('/pay/campaign', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pay():
    user = User.query.get_or_404(campaign.user_id)
    amount = 1000
    return render_template('payment.html', amount=amount, user=user)
```

and I want to access the variables `amount` and `user` in my JavaScript file and send them as a POST request to another Flask route `/pay_now`.

These variables are used in the `/pay_now` route to create a variable called `clientSecret` which I then need to be sent back to my JavaScript file to be used in the `confirmCardPayment()` method below. (If there is a way I can define these variables in `/pay` and access them directly in `/pay_now` without going through the JavaScript, that will work too)

```
@payment.route('/pay_now', methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_payment():
    clientSecret = create_secret(amount, user) #assume this creates secret
    return jsonify({"clientSecret": clientSecret})
```

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
fetch("/pay_now", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      // not sure how to send amount and user variable to /pay_now
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },

  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    // not sure how to read JSON from /pay_now

  });
  
  stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: card,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen'
      }
    }
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In summary, I need to:

1. Send `amount` and `user` from the `/pay` route to my JavaScript file
2. Then need to pass the `amount` and `user` variable to a Flask API route `/pay_now` which creates a variable called `clientSecret`
3. Finally, fetch the `clientSecret` variable and use it in the JavaScript file

Would be super awesome to get some help on this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `data` should be available where you had `// not sure how to read JSON from /pay_now`? Might be useful to include a `console.log(data)` to see what's there inside your browser's debug console to verify.

Comment: Okay thanks, will check that. Do you know how to access `amount` and `user` in the JavaScript from the `/pay` route?

Comment: {{amount}} or {{user}} I believe this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template

Comment: there could be a better way ... but you can do as `"{{ amount }}" and "{{ user }}"`