# Get json from flask using an external js file

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a flask server spitting out json data converted from pandas dataframe which look like:

```
[{'name': 'FBtr0075557',
  'score': '164.00'},
 {'name': 'FBtr0075557',
  'score': '162.00'}]
```

The python code I'm using to convert the dataframe to json and serve in flask is:

```
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
return render_template('mirtar.html', targets=json.dumps(parsed))
```

When I use internal javascript, the data is parsed without any error:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
const targets = {{ targets|tojson }};
const entries = JSON.parse(targets);
console.log(entries);
</script>
```

However when I try to do the same using an external JS script, I get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position
```

From what I understand, the line

```
const targets = {{ targets|tojson }};
```

in the external javascript doesn't behave the same way as in internal and the first '{' of the line is considered as an error.
I'm sure this is a very basic problem and there must be an easy way to do it that I have definitely missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja syntax is only parsed in flask html templates, not externally loaded JS assets: because it's the python app doing the parsing, and in a deployed environment you'd typically serve static assets with a webserver like nginx.

The quickest way to sort this might be with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840756/2052575) where instead you use a data attribute within an HTML element.  This appreciates that you're passing data to the template as an argument to `render_template`, so the data *is* present in the template at page load.

In your case this might look like

```
<!-- a hidden tag -->
<input type='hidden' id='targetid' data-thetargets='{{ targets|tojson }}' />
```

Then in your javascript load it up with:

```
var targets = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("targetid").dataset.thetargets);
```