# Is there a way to convert the "#&34;" back to a double quotation mark in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm using python to create a json string such as:

```py
jsonData = '{id: "idStr", name: "nameStr"}'
prs = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonData))
```

I then use flask to render my html template and pass in the prs variable as the value to create my data table. However, I need the quotations around idStr and nameStr to remain quotation marks. Instead they convert to #&34; in my html file. I was just wondering if there was a simple method to accomplish this or if I am just going at it the incorrect way.

The reason why I need the quotes for the values is because I'm using AnyChart to create a Gantt Chart visualization.

Output:

```py
data = [{id: #&34;idStr#&34;, name: #&34;nameStr#&34;}]
```

Comment: Can you make it an object? Must it be a string? like so: `jsonData = {...}`

Comment: have you tried using `\"` instead of `"` ? or using triple-quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: the Python part does not make much sense to me. How it differs from `prs = jsonData`?

Comment: So I'm using AnyChart to create a gantt chart using javascript, and so the data object in AnyChart is created like: `data = [{ id: "ProjectID", name: "ProjectName",}]. so the value for each field has to be in quotations. New to JS so apologies.

Comment: @Sina yea i tried using the backslash and triple quotes but it just converts the quotes to the #&34; like usual

Comment: What anychart produces is a JavaScript Object - not JSON. It is not valid JSON since the property names does not have qoutation marks.

Comment: This answer from the duplicate should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23071187/218196

Comment: @FelixKling, do you think it is even possible then to use JSON to help create an AnyChart JavaScript Object from Python input? I took a look at the duplicate and the "tojson" filter did allow for the array to be passed through, but requires quotations around the property names like fredrik stated.

Comment: I think the concerns about quotation marks are irrelevant if you use the `tojson` filter.