# How to use Python Flask variables in Javascript

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python variable whose value is a string of text and would like to edit that value via Javascript.

I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Attempts:

```
function changeValue(val) {
  val = 'new text';
}


<textarea placeholder="some text">{{ changeValue({{ result }}) }}</textarea>
```

```
<textarea placeholder="some text">
  {{ result }}
</textarea>
```

What I want: I have some text (result) being added and would like to check if the text is empty. If so, I want to show the placeholder text.
The issue: Although I can check if the value is empty, when I try to print that result out it reads `none`

Thanks to all!

Comment: is there any particular reason for using js

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template

Comment: @louisjoseph Yes, I edited the OP for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call the JavaScript function from the HTML file. There are several approaches you can take:

**1. Store the variable in HTML metadata:**

```
<meta id="result_var" data-result={{result}}>
```

And then get the data in JavaScript:

```
result = document.getElementById("result_var").value;
```

**2. Keep the variable in the tag where it's supposed to be and get it from there in JavaScript:**

```
<textarea placeholder="some text" id="result-var"> {{result}} </textarea>
```

And then get it in JavaScript:

```
let result = document.getElementById("result-var");
```

**3. Query it from your API:** You can create a route in your Flask app that returns JSON data with the variable you need and then get that data to your JavaScript file by sending a request to your API.

**4. Jinja format:** I've seen solutions that involve just using the variable as if it was a jinja variable in JavaScript like this: `let result = JSON.parse('{{ result | tojson }}');`. But I haven't been able to get this working properly, not sure why.

I hope this helps!